# IndexError: list index out of range when creating 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, loops, indexing

I am trying to get a 2D array with size 235x20 such that for each of the 235 ROI, I extract 20 elements based on the indices stored in `find_bootstrap_indices` and save them in `extract_bootstrap_timepoint`. Now, I want to store the values of each ROI and its corresponding 20 elements in an array. I have tried to do so by having this line `new[roi][timepoint] = extract_bootstrap[timepoint]` but I am having index out of range error. Any help on how to solve this will be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

```
new = []
for roi in range(0, rsfMRI_timeseries_2d.shape[0]):
        extract_bootstrap_timepoint = np.take(rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[roi, :], find_bootstrap_indices)
        for timepoint in range(0, len(extract_bootstrap_timepoint)):
            new[roi][timepoint] = extract_bootstrap_timepoint[timepoint]
```

Comment: You need to create the `new[roi]` list before assigning to it. Like `new[roi] = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers already cover how to fix the error, but don't mention that there's a lot easier way of doing the whole thing.

Broadly, I can think of a few different reasons why people use Numpy:

1. Numpy arrays can be faster than Python lists, if you have lots of data per array, don't need to convert back and forth between Numpy arrays and python lists and you use Numpy operations which implicitly operate on the whole array, instead of looping over single elements explicitly
2. Code using Numpy arrays can be more concise, since you can often eg. replace multiple nested loops with a single Numpy operation
3. You just want to use some functions which are already available in Numpy

You're missing out on points 1 and 2; You're using Numpy, but you aren't taking full advantage of it, so your code isn't as fast and concise as it could be.

First, a few non-Numpy words of advice:

- Unless you're using the three-argument form of `range()`, you can omit the start position if it's 0 - ie. `range(N)` does the same thing as `range(0, N)`
- If you're iterating over all the indexes of a list/array, and you're only using them for directly indexing said array (ie. not for eg. calculations), you should just directly iterate over the values instead - ie. instead of `for i in range(len(items)): item = items[i]`, you should do `for item in items:`. If you also need the index, you can say `for i, item in enumerate(items):`
- In your inner loop, you're just copying items over one-by one - if you don't need to do anything to the items individually, just do it in one go: (I'll be shortening `extract_bootstrap_timepoint` to `ebt`)

  - If the type is okay, and you don't need a copy, just assign it like `new[roi] = ebt`
  - If it's an array (like here) and you want a list, just convert it first with `new[roi] = list(ebt)` or `new[roi] = ebt.tolist()` (latter only works with arrays)
  - If it's already a list, and you need a copy, just do a copy, like `new[roi] = ebt.copy()` or `new[roi] = ebt[:]` (latter doesn't work with arrays)
  - If you already have a longer list, and you just want to overwrite as much items as you have, you can use slice assignment like `new[roi][:len(ebt)] = ebt`

So, applying that advice, your code simplifies to:

```
new = []
for row in rsfMRI_timeseries_2d:
        new.append(np.take(row, find_bootstrap_indices).tolist())
```

Now, onto the more Numpy-specific advice:

- `np.take(arr, indices)` does fancy indexing; In specific, if `arr` is a Numpy array and `indices` is a Python list, it's equivalent to `arr[indices]`
- Normal Numpy indexing returns a new view to the same shared data, but when you use fancy indexing, you get a copy of the data (so even if you need a copy, no need to explicitly copy in that case)

Since you're just doing the same thing to each row in `rsfMRI_timeseries_2d`, and the `np.take` call can be replaced by indexing as well, the whole loop can be replaced with:

```
new = rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[:,find_bootstrap_indices].tolist()
```

Although, since you're using Numpy, you'll probably want to be working with Numpy arrays instead of nested Python lists - If so, the whole thing becomes just:

```
new = rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[:,find_bootstrap_indices]
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for the great explanations and showing an optimised way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new[roi][] before assigning to it ie:

```
new = []
for roi in range(0, rsfMRI_timeseries_2d.shape[0]):
        extract_bootstrap_timepoint = np.take(rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[roi, :], find_bootstrap_indices)
        new[roi] = []
        for timepoint in range(0, len(extract_bootstrap_timepoint)):
            new[roi][timepoint] = extract_bootstrap_timepoint[timepoint]
```

Comment: That wouldn't work though: You create an empty list, but you can only refer to existing indexes or you'll get and IndexError. You'll either have to use `list.append()` or make the list big enough right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This creates the list of elements and manipulates value

```
new = [0]*rsfMRI_timeseries_2d.shape[0]
for roi in range(0, rsfMRI_timeseries_2d.shape[0]):
    xtract_bootstrap_timepoint = np.take(rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[roi, :], find_bootstrap_indices)
    new[roi]=[0]*len(extract_bootstrap_timepoint)
    for timepoint in range(0, len(extract_bootstrap_timepoint)):
        new[roi][timepoint] = extract_bootstrap_timepoint[timepoint]
```

One more method is to append values.

```
new = []
for roi in range(0, rsfMRI_timeseries_2d.shape[0]):
    xtract_bootstrap_timepoint = np.take(rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[roi, :], find_bootstrap_indices)
    l=list()
    for timepoint in range(0, len(extract_bootstrap_timepoint)):
        l.append(extract_bootstrap_timepoint[timepoint])
    new.append(l)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solutions. It works up to a point. If I use your first solution, then the length of new is 235. May I know how do I modify it such that new is 235x20 which represents roi by timepoint. Thank you.

Comment: new[roi]=[0]*len(extract_bootstrap_timepoint)
This line creates 20 elements for every new[i]

Comment: Great, I have one last question. Now that I have the new array with size 235x20. May I know if I wish to repeat that for N subjects, then how do I append it outside the for loops. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: new=[[0]*235]*20.This will create 2D array   I hope u are asking this

Comment: In essence, I wish to compute the correlation matrix of the array new with 235x20 using the numpy.corrcoef function for each subject. If I wish to do that, would numpy.corrcoef(new) for each subject make sense? The correction matrix needs to be done with roi x timepoint. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah you can do with it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it something like this:

```
new = []
for roi in range(0, rsfMRI_timeseries_2d.shape[0]):
    extract_bootstrap_timepoint = np.take(rsfMRI_timeseries_2d[roi, :], find_bootstrap_indices)
    new[roi] = extract_bootstrap_timepoint[:] # Copy data.
```

Comment: Normal indexing in Numpy always returns a view, so `arr[:]` doesn't return a copy; Fancy indexing (which `np.take()` does) always returns a copy though, so you don't need an explicit copy here at all. (Though `np.take()` returns an array, so if you want a list-of-lists instead of a list-of-arrays, you'll need to do a conversion - which would result in a fresh list anyway)